# I Just Created a Tag - Was I Right?

Tags: discussion, tags

I just posted a question on Stackoverflow about Prolog and trying to create a fact using the Jekejeke Android Runtime. I don't yet know if my question relates to Prolog, or to that particular runtime, so I added a Jekejeke tag. My logic was, we have tags for other tools/IDEs/intepreters like Eclipse, so it seemed helpful to have one, but it worries me that no one else has ever created it.

Should I remove the tag?

Comment: Well, there is [one other question](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Jekejeke+), which is off-topic btw, so unless this is new IDE that will see a flood of new questions coming in I doubt if it really helps in finding questions....

Comment: Yeah, I'm surprised there aren't any but the stats don't lie :-)

Comment: Is this jekejeke thing only used in the context of prolog? Prolog by itself is not a major tag so you can't expect a lot of questions in a subtag in that case. It doesn't hurt to have the tag. If you provide a tag wiki and excerpt maybe more users will find it...

Comment: Thanks @rene. It looks like someone has already leapt in there and added a tag wiki

Comment: @Disco3: It would have helped a lot to call this tag jekejeke-prolog instead. Well, it was your decision to make it as you did.